# Add double quotes around variable -Full text search sql server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I am trying to execute full text search into one of my table.

I found that adding double quotes is must while working with full text search.

This one works fine.

```
SELECT *  FROM tblArea WHERE CONTAINS ((District,Taluka,VillageName,Area),'"rajkot 2"')
```

When i used this in node.js where the search input is from web application.

```
    let src='"'+req.params.data+'"';
         
    MsSqlQuery = SqlString.format(`SELECT * FROM tblArea WHERE 
    CONTAINS ((District,Taluka,VillageName,Area),?)`,[src]);
```

This results out in syntax error as output.

May i know how can i add double quotes around variable ?

Comment: I think the issue is you're missing the single quotes. In your SQL statement, the last part is `,'"rajkot 2"')`. In your code, the equivalent src (e.g., via params) would be `"rajkot2"`. Then when put into the query, it would be `,"rajkot 2")` e.g., missing the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked

MsSqlQuery_New = SqlString.format(`SELECT District,Taluka,VillageName,Area   FROM tblArea WHERE CONTAINS ((District,Taluka,VillageName,Area),'"${req.params.searchInput}"')`);